# Cannot add activity in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-activity, build.gradle

I completed the Firebase Friendly Chat tutorial (https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/#0) and the chat runs fine. I am trying to expand it by adding a new activity: app, New, Activity, Empty Activity. Immediately after the activity is added I get this gradle build error:

```
Error:(46, 0) Could not get unknown property 'compile' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
<a href="openFile:C:\Users\apand\AndroidStudioProjects\android-startPure\play\app\build.gradle">Open File</a>
```

This also error also occurs with the beginning tutorial code (android-start). How do I fix this so that another activity can be added to this code?

Here is the build.gradle code from the module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile
    'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'compile
    'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'compile
    'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'compile
    'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'compile
    'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.0'compile 
'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.1.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: add your  `build.gradle` file

Comment: The build.gradle is added. As mentioned, the sample code works perfectly fine and I chat and everything. It is just when I add a new activity as described I get the error. Why would just adding a new activity to code that is otherwise working fine cause this type gradle build crash? Can anyone replicate this with the Friendly Chat tutorial code?

Comment: @Aneel Panfey, Atef means post your gradle file here.

Comment: Most possibly you are missing plugin import.

Comment: I added the build.gradle module file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `dependencies` block of the `build.gradle`.

Try replacing it with

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.1.1'
}
```